# How to install boruta in python using conda install

Tags: python, conda

I'm using python 3.6 on windows 10. I want to install boruta in my python.
So I used following command `conda install -c conda-forge r-boruta` but got error message

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
```

I also tried `conda install boruta` but got the same error message. Can you suggest me installation steps

Comment: Why don't you use `pip install boruta`

Comment: The package is not available through conda for Windows it seems [check here](https://anaconda.org/search?q=r-boruta)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge

conda install r-boruta
```

Source: https://github.com/conda-forge/r-boruta-feedstock

Comment: There is no r-boruta in conda-forge for Windows

Comment: Also, there is no difference if you specify `-c` on the conda install or adding a channel using `config --add`

Comment: @FlyingTeller there is search it here https://conda-forge.org/feedstocks/

Comment: Click on the entry and check the build status. It says Windows: disabled. You can slo check [here](https://anaconda.org/search?q=r-boruta)

Answer (score 0):

As per official documentation of anaconda https://anaconda.org/saravji/boruta if you want to install boruta using conda install use **conda install -c saravji boruta** or  **conda install -c conda-forge boruta_py** and make sure that your python version is less than equal to 3.6.